# gcc optimization flag: it "fixes" the code

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Basically, I have a piece of code that converts a function pointer to an object pointer type. During compilation I see this warning

```
ISO C forbids conversion of function pointer to object pointer type
```

The code works without any problem if the optimization flag is active, for example

```
gcc -O1
```

As soon as I remove all the optimizations the code breaks, for example

```
gcc -O0 -ggdb
```

After months of research I found the problem that breaks my code but I don't understand why the release build (optimization active) works.

Basically what I have in the code is an array where each object in the array is a function pointer. The functions are defined with a macro and have a void return type. In order to access to the function through the array I need to cast the function definition with `(void *)` and this is where the compiler complains about.

Is the optimization flag that does the magic under the hood?

**EDIT: Added code example**

Here is a code example:

```
static const struct
{
    UINT8       parameter1;
    UINT8       parameter2;
    UINT8       parameter3;
    void *      function1;
    void *      function2;
} handlerList[] =
{
    { 8, 12, 0, (void *)FUNC1, (void *)FUNC2 },
    { 12, 24, 1, (void *)FUNC3, (void *)FUNC4 },
    { 3, 12, 2, (void *)FUNC5, (void *)FUNC6 },
};
```

**FUNC1**, **FUNC2**... are macros that define all the functions with `void` return type.

When I have to pass (returning it) the function pointer to other code I use this snippet:

```
return handlerList[i].function1
```

In which way I can define an array of function pointer and recall it without convert function pointer to object pointer?

**EDIT: Added compilation flag**

It doesn't work with `gcc -O0 -ggdb` but it works, rebuilding only the source code that contains the code in the example, with `gcc -O0 -ggdb -ftree-coalesce-vars`.

What -ftree-coalesce-vars does?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248612/discussion-on-question-by-francesco-gcc-optimization-flag-it-fixes-the-code).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your code but i'll try to guess.
Suppose you have:

```c
int main(void)
{
    int *p = main; // This is UB!
    *p = *p;

    return 0;
}
```

`p` is an object type pointer but it holds function pointer value. On many architectures code and data are in the same address space but pages with code sections are read-only.
With `-O1` compiler just eliminates `*p=*p` as useless operation and nothing happen.
With `-O0` compiler generates code which attempts to write to read-only page.

Comment: Basically what I have in the code is an array where each object in the array is a function pointer. The functions are defined with a macro and have a void return type. In order to access to the function through the array I need to cast the function definition with (void *) and this is where the compiler complains about

Comment: How array element type is related to function's return type? Compiler shouldn't complain if everything is defined correctly. Otherwise you have an error and `-O1` masks it.

Comment: Added code example in the OP

Comment: It's UB. You can declare structure with function pointer as the only member and return structure from your functions. Or declare `function1` and `function2` as array and return `i` and index in functions array either in structure or by pointers to `int` in arguments.

Comment: It doesn't work with `gcc -O0 -ggdb` but it works, rebuilding only the source that contains the code in the example of OP, with `gcc -O0 -ggdb -ftree-coalesce-vars`

Comment: @Francesco If it works in some particular cases it doesn't mean "it is correct". If you call a function with one signature by a pointer with another signature, it is undefined behavior. Provide reproducible example and we could point what's wrong.

Comment: As I said before, it is an emulator, I can't post the entire source code. It has a dynamic recompiler inside, using `(void *)` is necessary when you have to execute instructiom code directly, isn't it? What `-ftree-coalesce-vars` does here? I'm trying to understand what the flag changes, converting object pointer to function pointer maybe is not the problem when the size of the pointer are the same

Comment: @Francesco Flags are described in gcc manual. You still didn't say what "doesn't work" mean in your case. Segmentation fault? Locate what line of code causes it by analyzing core dump with gdb. How FUNC macros are defined? How functions are called? Gcc can dump intermediate results of every compilation/optimization stage, from preprocessing till assembly listing, compare them.  Compare disassembled code at least. There are lot of methods of debugging instead of asking to guess why some unknown code doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I already wrote what doesn't work in another comment before you start this thread of comments. **When the problem occurs the main loop is running but I see on the video only a garbage, no sound, always the same video frame**

Answer (score 0):

The reason the C Standard does not define conversions between function and data pointers is they may have different representations, including a different size. Most compilers will generate correct code if code and data pointers happen to have the same size on the target architecture, yet the warning is important and you should define `function1` and `function2` as function pointers with an appropriate prototype.

In your case, this is not the likely explanation for your observations, but it is unclear what happens when you write `{ 8, 12, 0, (void *)FUNC1, (void *)FUNC2 },` because `FUNC1` and `FUNC2`, as macros, are probably not function expressions at all.

Comment: If FUNC1 and FUNC2 weren't functions the application won't work

Comment: @Francesco: if you post the full code to a compilable example, we shall be able to tell you what the problem is. With just a fragment, not much more can be diagnosed.

Comment: It doesn't work with `gcc -O0 -ggdb` but it works, rebuilding only the source that contains the code in the example of OP, with `gcc -O0 -ggdb -ftree-coalesce-vars`